# csc.exe exited with code -2146232797 vs 2017

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, roslyn, csc

I have error in my project on time of build csc.exe exited with code -2146232797 visual studio 2017(Professional) in other Team's computer project building and running fine, so I not want to update nuget compiler,
Is there any permanent solutions there?

Comment: What about the rest of the build log? I'm betting that describes the problem you're having in human-readable terms, instead of only a cryptic error code. (You can turn up the build verbosity in the preferences if the output window doesn't show enough detail.)

Comment: Maybe search for 0x80131623 ?

Comment: It is nasty, the C# compiler decided to quit with Environment.FailFast().  Try it on a do-nothing C# source file, if it still fails then you know you have an install problem.  Pretty likely.  If not then comment out chunks of code to narrow down the trouble statement.

Comment: Since this is the top result when searching for this error code, [I'm gonna link to this answer to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63584334/3337288). The basic message being, check your code before reinstalling .NET. This would have saved me hours.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This issue happened for some people with vs 2017. you need to  reinstall .net via

[microsoft site](https://www.microsoft.com/net/download/framework)

as requested and if the above link does not help, there is a thread in [visual studio development community](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/94629/error-msb6006-cscexe-exited-with-code-2146232797.html) stating they fixed the issue in visual studio 2017 v15.5:

> We have fixed this issue and it's available in Visual Studio 2017
>   version 15.5. Thank you for helping us build a better Visual Studio!

more over, there is another solution stating:

> using the 2.2 compiler made the problem go away.

Comment: Press Windows+ R, in RUN type appwiz.cpl, then uninstall change window will come.
Then find the Microsoft .Net Framework, repair it.
This has fixed my issue for VS 2017.

Answer (score 1):

Multiple times I got this issue in VS 2019. I closed other VS projects and then build successfully.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/29998316)

Comment: I got "csc.exe" exited with code -2146232797 msg (.NetFramework 4.7.2), and I wasted couple of hours to solve it but failed. If someone wants to save his hour while in rush in coding....so shared my way...thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It may be caused by the Windows drive being full.